# how to document conditional statements like if and switch in phpDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

```
if($condition){

$i = $i + 1;

}
else 
{
$i = $i - 1;
}
```

How can i document a simple if, else condition in phpDoc?

Comment: What are you trying to do.

Comment: I'm a little late, but Google just sent me here. What ARE you trying to do? Are you trying to hint at the return types? This is doable now: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#conditional-return-types

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like this:

```
if ($condition)
{
    /**
     * This will increase counter
     */
    $i = $i + 1;
} else
{
    /**
     * This will decrease counter
     */
    $i = $i - 1;
}
```

See doc: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.ignore.pkg.html